# Setting individual values in ASPxGridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, devexpress

I have a ASPxGridView that gets populated from a database. Everything in my code works correctly (about 95% sure of this) and I essentially want to call

```
e.SetValue("MeanTime") = meanTimeCell;
```

Unfortunately this does not exist. I have searched for this but cannot find an answer.

```
protected void RTMonitoringGrid_HtmlRowCreated(object sender, DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridViewTableRowEventArgs e)
     if (e.RowType == DevExpress.Web.GridViewRowType.Data) 
     {
        //this gets a value in the GridView 
        string meanTimeCell = e.GetValue("MeanTime").ToString();

        try
        {
           double result;
           if (double.TryParse(meanTimeCell, out result))
           {  
              //this is the string I essentially want to overwrite the old cell data with
              meanTimeCell = string.Format("{0}s", Math.Round(result, 1));
              //SetValue would be called here
           }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
     }
}
```

Does anyone know an easy fix for this? I have thought of trying to format data before it gets put in the ASPxGridView but I think that would prove equally difficult.

Comment: You have to `Update` your database at some point. Do you have a method written to accomplish updates?

Comment: I have not worked with much of the code in the project. The database I have was imported for me but I could probably find an Update statement if needed.

Comment: Okay great. You need to alter a few events of your `GridView` such as `OnRowEditing` and `OnRowUpdating` to handle the update processes. [Here's an example](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Simple-Insert-Select-Edit-Update-and-Delete-in-ASPNet-GridView-control.aspx) that includes steps on how to set up your `GridView`.

Comment: DevExpress's GridView has different methods than the normal asp GridView. The above example will not fix the problem I am having.

Comment: You do not need to update anything just to display a rounded version of the number

Answer (score 0):

Make an unbound column and handle the gridviews onCustomUnboundColumnData event. In that event, set the value to whatever you want it to be.

EDIT: actually since you only need to round the number from the database (if you are willing to drop the s on the end of it)  Simply set the column's DisplayFormat.FormatType to "Numeric" and DisplayFormat.FormatString to display however many decimal places you want.

You could also follow the approach in the devexpress thread listed [Here](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q291210)